# SharePoint - WSS 2.0, How can I get the authenticated user name with Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: sharepoint

I've been trying various methods to accomplish this with no success. I can only use client-side scripting.  I'm a newb at this...is it even possible?

Some additional details:

- I'm currently working with a list in a subsite, and want to grab the username of the  authenticated user to add to a list.
- I'm successfully using: http://code.google.com/p/yasq/ to add/delete/modify list items
- I don't have admin access to the main site.
- I've tried SPServices, but can't get it to return any data.

Answer (score 1):

This is available via core.js and init.js. You can get the SharePoint user id of the currently logged in user and then do a lookup against the user profile service.

If you have a layout that includes core.js and init.js you can use the global **_spUserId** variable that is part of the current context. Just be sure to have your script loads after SharePoint's JavaScript by using _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("YourWrapperFunction").

In SP 2010 you can simply use the ClientContext object provided by the client object model. currCtx = new ClientContext(currentWebUrl); More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee536158.aspx

If all else fails you can do what the YASQ library you referenced is doing and make a request to a page that displays information about the user, such as _layouts/userdisp.aspx, and scrape the info from the result with regexes.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'm unable to locate core.js and init.js on my server under any of my /_layout/1033/ folders.  Any suggestions on where I could find those files, or how I can create a layout that includes them?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly solution I wrote a long time ago:

`function getCurrentUser()
{
    var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
 for (var i=0; i < tags.length; i++)
 {
    if(tags[i].innerText.substr(0,7) == 'Welcome')
    {
    return tags[i].innerText.substr(8,tags[i].innerText.length);
    }
 }
}`

// look through all the A tags, find one that starts out 'welcome' and pull out the name of the person logged in.